# Cloud9 app memory and disk space limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, railstutorial.org, cloud9-ide

I'm making my way through chapter 6 Michael Hartl tutorial [www.railstutorial.org/book] using the Cloud9 IDE and server has stopped running due to memory limits. I am using the free tier which comes with 512MB Ram. I've tried force killing processes using the Disk/Memory/CPU menu. I've also tried killing spring in bash with

```
pkill -9 -f spring
```

Ive also tried the suggestions in box 3.4 at the end of Chapter 3.

```
$ ps aux | grep spring
```

ubuntu   11419  0.0  0.0  10548   852 pts/1    S+   19:22   0:00 grep --color=auto spring

```
$ kill -9 11419
bash: kill: (11419) - No such process
```

Anyone have any pointers!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the best place to ask. First off, read this about [Avoiding to use `kill -9`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process). Second, although Cloud9 has rails pre-packaged for the tutorial, I suggest Koding, where you get 3GB space (2.5 after launching your workspace), and 1GB of RAM. It also uses Ubuntu VM. If you are interested, I can (shamelessly) post my referral link.

Comment: Thanks for that but its a fairly small application and shouldn't use that much space. I've seen other questions referencing rogue spring processes hogging all the memory. Confused if there is some reason why killing them does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That process you see running after doing ps aux | grep spring is actually grep finding itself (as you can see grep in the name). It appears there are no spring processes running.

You should have received 768MB of ram for the Rails tutorial workspace, and if you write into Cloud9 support they'll give you some additional swap space so that you no longer have any issues hitting the memory limit. (I work for Cloud9 and this will be implemented across all workspaces soon)